# To what extent is English aware of Identity Politics? False dichotomy in sexual\gender orientation

Tags: terminology, articles, academia

In the course of translating an academic paper, reading about sample of male participants which, from what they reported, partly consisted of gays, straights, and asexuals, as cited below, I have run into a dilemma concerned with Identity Politics (So I believe, I haven't arrived at any other term):

> "...in a sample of 135 males with eating disorders, 42% of the bulimic patients considered themselves to be either gay or bisexual. In the same study, 58% of the men described them- selves as “asexual”...".

Having been involved in the feminist discourse for quite a while in the past, I am in a state where I genuinely wonder whether or not asexuality came at the expense of sexual attraction (or should I rather say- gender preference and\or display of interest in one gender or more in a romantic or other manner) in that survey. Although the different terms within that spectrum seem to be unequivocally set, this complex terminology is vague, and, as much as I respect the academy and acknowledge its importance,  it seems to have been determined by individuals not sufficiently familiar with the volatility of sexual-romantic-orientations. Maybe it is yet to be scientifically determined that asexuality doesn't contradict homosexuality or other orientations, I don't really know. On one hand, I believe that in the survey mentioned above, asexuality indicates absence of sexual\gender preference, but on the other hand, it's also been considered that eating disorders are used, knowingly or not, as a way to become asexual (by halting hormonal and sexual development feared to confront the subjects with their sexual identity crisis and\or to enable sexual experience which might be traumatic to some of them.).

It's been considered that asexuals might have gender preference for relationships, but is it really reflected in the case I presented? I am not native and my English is basically poor, and I thought you could give me your point of view on that matter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about the English language.

Comment: The excerpt you quote above makes little sense.  You need to ask the authors of the study what they meant.  (And one needs to keep in mind that English "experts", as a rule, are hermits.)

Comment: So what is it about? To me it all comes down to English terminology. As I wished you had read, I am not native, have a difficult time navigating to the exact forums, and I have no indication of what areas of discussion I should be focusing at. You could at least give me a tiny hint as for where I should be headed to.

Comment: Your above "question" is simply a lot of speculation about some rather nebulous terminology.  The brief excerpt you quote makes no sense, especially without more context.  And in any event this is a question for people who deal with sexuality issues, not the intricacies of English.  There may be a SE site that is suitable for such questions, but I doubt it.  More likely you need to go to another site, if you can't get your question answered from the authors.

Comment: I am thankful for your suggestions, less thankful for the discouraging way in which they were delivered. Even in case I am wrong in choosing to ask this question on here, I believe I have been respectful and accepting enough to not be responded in such a patronizing way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the point of view of standard English usage, the word *asexual* has two meanings. The first is a method of reproduction in which two members of a species each contributes half the genetic material needed to form a new member of the species. This can't be what the paper refers to, so if the word is used in a standard way, it means the absence of sexual desire. It would be natural to conclude that since an asexual reports no sexual urges, he or she has no preference in satisfying non-existent desires. That is to say, it would be natural to conclude, as you've done, that along with an absence of desire, "asexuality indicates absence of sexual\gender preference."

But terminology can take you only so far in understanding sexual preference or identify, which is a complex amalgam of habit, practice, and feeling. Those in the study who self-reported as asexuals may also have declared themselves straight, gay, or bi based on the preferences they had before they lost their sexual urges or based on the patterns of their current sexual behavior (The latter need not be the empty set, as people have sex even when they're not in the mood.)

Alas, understanding the sexuality of the sample population cannot be found in English usage. You'll have to consult the paper's methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Either the presentation of the material by the authors is wrong, or you are yanking our chain.

42% of a population cohort as homosexual or bisexual? I don't think so. Maybe if it were an HIV clinic.

58% as asexual? 42 + 58 = 100. Try again. So no bulimics are heterosexual?

Next time you read a study, try to absorb the results a bit first, and then determine if it's worth spending time on.

Comment: But under Eating Disorders, Bulimia is one type mentioned. Also mentioned is Anorexia. Yes, I see the percents add up to 100, but 42% are from bulimic patients, and it has not been stated whether or not the 58% are bulimic as well.

Comment: "42% **of the bulimic patients** considered themselves to be either gay or bisexual" means that the other 58% "of the bulimic patients" *did not*  "consider themselves to be either gay or bisexual".  As I read it, the next sentence states that "58% of the men" **with eating disorders - not necessarily the bulimic ones** - described themselves as “asexual”".  Without any indication of, of link to, the source of the quotation, you are asking us to interpret the sentence **out of context**.